# Will gas from a failed ERC 20 token creation be returned?

Tags: contract-deployment, gas, erc-20

I recently attempted  to create a new ERC 20 through MyEtherWallet and the creation failed due to `Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]`.

Below is some information about the gas from the transaction and the full transaction can be found at:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0f2e83db40bfd43c38360dc5507b5d7cb5751093f9a88b456eea1b5627e87601

```
Gas Limit: 750022 
Gas Used By Txn: 750022 
Gas Price: 0.000000099 Ether (99 Gwei) 
Actual Tx Cost/Fee: 0.074252178 Ether ($50.57)
```

It has been over 24 hours already from this failed transaction. My question is whether or not the gas from the transaction will be returned to my wallet or is it lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, like any another "out of gas" transaction, the ether (associated to the gas) is not returned.
Same reason as always: prevent a DoS attack by a user creating a lot of "out of gas" transactions

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is correct, gas (in general) is an anti-DDos mechanism.

To add to that answer, A simple way to think about it is this. The miner who won the block (and all other miners for that matter) had to run the calculation in order to determine that you didn’t provide enough gas for what you were trying to do. To be fair, the miner needs to get paid even though the transaction failed. Therefor, gas is forfeit for failed transactions.